# Scala - order of methods execution

Tags: scala, runtime

I created a code in InteliJ for testing Maps behavior:

```
object Maps {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello")
  }

  def myMethod(myhash: Map[String, String]) = {
    for ((k, v) <- myhash) printf("key: %s, value: %s\n", k, v)

  }
  myMethod(Map("test1" -> "test2"))

  val m1 = Map[Int, Int](1 -> 1)

  for ((k, v) <- m1) printf("key: %s, value: %s\n", k, v)

}
```

It works fine but I am surprised with execution ORDER.

Output:

```
  key: test1, value: test2
    key: 1, value: 1
    Hello
```

Are actions in `main` always executed last? (after all other methods)

Comment: the author didn't say he's using intellij. and is not saying this happened on a test. he wrote code to check the behaviour @RameshMaharjan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the code that is inside `object Maps {...}`, but not inside a method, is part of `Maps`' constructor. When your program is executed, first the `Maps` object is created (which executes its constructor) and then the `main` method is called on that object.

So yes, the code outside of `main` (i.e. the constructor code) will run before the code inside `main` (and code inside other methods will run if and when those other methods are called).

Answer (score 1):

In scala object, The code outside the main method is part of constructor so as we know constructor is called at the time of object creation. This is the reason that your code is displaying content of maps.